# How to fix this Error: spawn EACCES - ionic cordova build ios

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

imac-de-mac-2:cov mac$ ionic cordova build ios

> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform ios
>   Error: spawn EACCES

```
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
at spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:17:18)
at spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:124:12)
at ShellCommand.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:113:16)
at ShellCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:80:24)
at Shell.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/shell.js:32:37)
at next (native)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:107:75
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about my first answer/comment that I have the same error.
Now I think I find out the solution:

You must set the correct permission in your App/Project folder with the following command:

chmod -Rv 755 *